# Unable to fetch data faster in cloudant DB

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudant, ibm-cloud

I was using cloud ant Db for my iOS app with name `tasks_master` with almost 1000 documents. When I tried to fetch data from cloud ant  it's taking almost 30 sec to fetch data i have tried with below code.

```
- (NSURL*) replicatorURL {    
    AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];       
    NSString *db_name = @"tasks_master";

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@%@.cloudant.com/%@",
                 username,
                 password,
                 username,db_name];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
}

- (void) sync:(UIViewController *)sender {
    [self pullReplication:sender];
    [self pushReplication:sender];
}


-(void)pullReplication:(UIViewController *)sender {
    [self log:@"Starting pull replication"];       
    NSURL *url = [self replicatorURL];

    AppDelegate *delegate1 = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CDTReplicatorFactory *factory = delegate1.replicatorFactory;

    CDTReplicator *replicator = [factory onewaySourceURI:url targetDatastore:delegate1.datastore];
    [self startAndFollowReplicator:replicator label:@"pull"];
}

- (void) pushReplication:(UIViewController *)sender {   
    [self log:@"Starting push replication"];

    NSURL *url = [self replicatorURL];
    AppDelegate *delegate1 = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    CDTReplicatorFactory *factory = delegate1.replicatorFactory;
    CDTReplicator *replicator = [factory onewaySourceDatastore:delegate1.datastore targetURI:url];
    [self startAndFollowReplicator:replicator label:@"push"];
}
```

when i call tasks

```
-(void)fetchtasks{
[[[CDTTodoReplicator alloc]init]sync];

self.indexManager = [[CDTIndexManager alloc] initWithDatastore:self.datastore

                                                         error:&error];   

indexName= [self.datastore ensureIndexed:@[@"originator",@"members",@"meeting_status"] withName:@"meeting_index"];  




query=@{@"$and":@[@{@"meeting_status":@"Scheduled"},                    @{@"$or":@[@{@"originator":app.userName},@{@"members":app.userName}]}]};


result = [self.datastore find:query];

}
```

can any one help me out how to fetch data faster .

Comment: Can you add a little more information about your indexes and makeup of your database?

Comment: [[[CDTTodoReplicator alloc]init]sync];
    self.indexManager = [[CDTIndexManager alloc] initWithDatastore:self.datastore
                                                             error:&error];   indexName= [self.datastore ensureIndexed:@[@"originator",@"members",@"meeting_status"] withName:@"meeting_index"];   query=@{@"$and":@[@{@"meeting_status":@"Scheduled"},                    @{@"$or":@[@{@"originator":app.userName},@{@"members":app.userName}]}]};
    result = [self.datastore find:query];

Comment: any how mobile sync is allowing to index data locally which is happening after sync operation .my problem is sync itself taking so much time.

Comment: Any chance you can make your database available for replication, so we can run some tests? Many thanks, Stefan, Cloudant.

Comment: i have written an email regarding my problem to cloudant support but they haven't replied till now. i just had taken a data base and inserted ten records and trying to fetch records using sync method as i mentioned above it's taking 20 sec -30 sec time to load data. i don't know why its happening any how i was ready to replicate my database can you tell me the process.

Comment: @xpqz can you help me how out,for instance i have 10 companies information in my DB when cloudant is calling sync method all company records are syncing which should not happen in real time.i should fetch records based on some condition .

Comment: Take a look at this video I made a while back: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VFkIzyWPYE -- I show how to sync a cloudant database to device. The database contains ~2000 docs, and syncs initially in a few seconds. The database is open for reading, so you should be able to try it as is.

Comment: nice tutorial i have watched it.one problem is when i was creating document its not showing under design document my design document is showing empty.when i click on "All Documents " i was able to see documents does its the reason why my data is loading slowly.

Comment: it worked like a magic thanks stefan you are awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a little helper class to cut down on some of the boiler plate for this kind of thing. It's the one used in the video referenced above.

Cloudant.h https://gist.github.com/xpqz/f8b304353080c3963a45

Cloudant.m https://gist.github.com/xpqz/62b5267c250f04c30f9b

When you add documents to a Cloudant database, they become available through the so called primary index, also known as All Docs. This can easily be checked with 'curl' from the command line, e.g.:

```
% curl https://skruger.cloudant.com/routes/_all_docs
```

Every document you store will appear in the returned data from the primary index.

Design documents are there for a different purpose - they define secondary indexes, called views, mostly written as little javascript functions that define a map-reduce operation to expose some facet of your data. Views allow you to index your documents in additional ways to the document id that you get for free.

You can create your own views directly by creating design documents yourself, but client software accessing the database sometimes also create design documents and views automatically which sometimes can be confusing when you see stuff appearing under _design that you didn't explicitly create.

In summary: every document appear in the primary index, _all_docs. Design documents are there to hold javascript functions used to generate secondary indexes, called views. These can be created explicitly, or generated automatically 'behind your back' by client software.

More info:

1. [Primary index and all docs](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/all_docs/)
2. [Design documents and secondary indexes](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/views/)
3. [Search indexes and Lucene](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/)

Stefan

Comment: .when i tried to save document through                       CDTDocumentRevision *doc = [self.datastore createDocumentFromRevision:rev error:error]; it is saving document in "All Documents",it's not storing in  Design Docs how to store document in design " Design Docs" in above example you have stored all data in design document.

Comment: I added a bit more info to my answer above.